# How do you find the electromagnetic force on a ball based if you already know the strength of said magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Basically, my situation is this. I am trying to create a nice simulation. I have an electromagnet and a ball. The electromagnet has a strength of one tesla(I don't know what strength to use yet). Now let's say the ball is 3 meters away. How many newtons of force is applied to the ball? What is the formula for finding this out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

first you have to calculate the *magnetic field B* at the place where ball is kept:

for electromagnet(a coil with N turns of length L)

> $B = \frac{u_0NI}{L}$

$u_0$ is permeability of free space = 4$\pi * 10^{-7}$

So calculate B(assume that the object is ferromagnetic means all field lines passes through it because you didn't mention the material of the ball)

> $F = \frac{B^2Vχ}{2μ0}$

Where B is magnetic field
V is volume of object

χ is magnetic susceptibility(it will depend of type of material you take)

$\mu_0$ permeability of free space

Just put the values you will get your answer

Comment: What do you mean when you say this works when the electromagnet is a long wire? Aren't electromagnets just long copper wire wrapped around a pipe with a metal rod through the center? So is this formula for just a rod with copper wire wrapped around it or is it something else? How would you find how the equation changes for different shapes? It would be very helpful because I am thinking of making different shapes of magnets do get my desired output such as semicircles.

Comment: Sorry @RocketMan I wrote formula of long wire (as you said I just realized,Im in class 12 and my physics final exams just ended so yeah i got confused) but I edited the answer now :) 
and about your question that does the magnetic field B changes so yes it does with change in shape
ampere circuital law: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law